# React.js search-box style -appearance warning

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[I don't know how to fix this error i've searched for a while and i'm really curious on how to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MAFm.png)

I've searched on stackoverflow i found something but not a fix to this warning, i think is something about the version but i'm not sure i'm not great at css

Comment: I saw your comment after I posted my answer sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the actual CSS property along with the webkit property as it applies to only specific browsers. Hence you get a warning from VS code.

Add the "appearance" property in CSS

`.search-box { appearance: none; -webkit-appearance:none }`

Comment: It worked, thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Vs code gives you that warning because of you are defining appearance only for webkit. It requires also standart property. Webkit prefixes used to browser compatibility. If you are curious about webkit you can check out [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions)

To fix warning just add [standart property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance)